# Condition for term-by-term differentiation of a non-convergent series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

In a problem I have seen, a series $\sum_n u_n(x)$ with $$ f_n(x) = \frac {\log(1+n^4x^2)}{2n^2}$$

here $\sum u_n'(x)$ is not uniformly convergent, BUT 
 If $f '(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x) $
 where $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) $

Then this series can be differentiated term by term, is this condition true everywhere for any series?

But the same condition fails for a series whose  $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $, this cannot be differntiated term by term at $x=0$, WHY?

Can we do term-by-term differentiation of a series which is not uniformly convergent?? If so what is the condition to be satisfied there?

Comment: Please look at my edits to this question.  Mathematical notation here should use MathJax.  Alternating in and out of MathJax the way you did should not be done. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to.  Only in the summation term i missed a"n" right?, I tried to use mathematical notation elsewhere

Comment: There are differences between \Sigma and \sum.  The former gives you this: $$ \Sigma_{n=1}^{100} a_n $$and the latter gives you this: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{100} a_n$$ But much of what you did here wasn't in MathJax at all. $\qquad$

Comment: Ok actually, I'm not familiar with MathJax , I usually search in google like "sigma symbol in stack exchange" and use that to write  my problem. Sorry.

Comment: Why do you have $f_n$ and $u_n$? I can't make sense out of the question.

Comment: fn is just sum of n terms of series, nth partial sum.

Comment: i.e. fn=u1+u2+........ +un